# Delete text between second pair of brackets but not first

Tags: bash, sed

After a few lines of grepping and sedding a set of phone logs, I end up with output like this:

```
[2019-07-18 14:12:57] [1563477176.20446]  '30' <redacted> at 162+
[2019-07-18 14:14:08] [1563477248.20463]  '30' <redacted> at 162+
[2019-07-18 14:19:20] [1563477559.20468]  '30' <redacted> at 162+
[2019-07-18 23:30:41] [1563510638.21273]  '30' <redacted> at 162+
[2019-07-18 23:31:21] [1563510678.21276]  '30' <redacted> at 162+
```

I've redacted the phone numbers for privacy.

I'd like to delete the gibberish between the second set of brackets here, as well as the second pair of brackets themselves. It corresponds to that call's unique call ID, and in the logs I like that (this is taken from a custom logging solution I wrote), but in this view I don't need it. I'd like to be concise and just display the timestamp and the number.

I found a related SE post about how to remove the text between brackets in sed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14838/sed-one-liner-to-delete-everything-between-a-pair-of-brackets

The one-liner in sed is `sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g'`

However, it looks like that would remove the text between **all** the brackets, which is not what I want.

Is there any way to make it skip over the contents of the first set of brackets on each line?

Since I know that the timestamp brackets will always be the same length, whereas the second set of brackets can be variable length as the part after the decimal can be any number of digits, I thought about perhaps using `${line:0:21}` to store the timestamp in a temp variable, then run the sed statement, and then concatenate the two back together. But I'm doing this as part of a statement in bash that's already ten pipes one after the other, so I don't know if that would work. Either way, it sounds like bad coding practice.

Is there any way to skip the first `[]` or must I split each line so I can use sed on the relevant part?

Comment: `awk '{$3 = ""}1' input`

Comment: or, (IMO slightly more cryptic): `awk '!($3 = "")' input`

Comment: a cryptic `sed` extended-regex `sed -nE 's/\[.*\].*\[(.*)\].*/\1/p'` input

Comment: @LéaGris That extracts instead of deletes, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sed's `s` command takes a digit as a flag to indicate which occurrence of the match the substitution should be applied to, so instead of `g` (all occurrences), you can use `2`:

```
sed 's/\[[^]]*\]//2'
```

You also don't need `[` within the bracket expression, unless you're expecting nested brackets, which your example input doesn't have.

---

References:

- [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-s-command_002c-option-flags)
- [POSIX sed manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)